# Is there a way to set the name box of a cell programmatically in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba, worksheet-function

I would like to programmatically set the name box of a cell in a worksheet I'm working on, either through a formula or through a macro.  The end point is that I don't want to set it by hand.

In my case based on the value in (say) cell D5 set the name box of E5 to the contents of D5.

I haven't seen a reference that would let me do this simply, so I suspect it's something that might have to be set through VBA.

Has anyone done this or can advise how to do this?

**edit**

[image: showing name box]

Comment: Are you talking about naming the range? I'm not clear on what you mean by "the name box of E5".

Comment: I probably am talking about naming the range, though here the range may only be 1 cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I think what I'm looking at (with credit to @Col and @StevenV for the big point in the right direction) is

```
activecell.name = activecell.offset( 0, -1 ).value
```

Comment: That looks like it will name the single active cell with the name as whatever is in the cell immediately above.  Is that what your trying to achieve?

Comment: A bit shorter `ActiveCell.Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value`.

Comment: @Col The cell to the left actually.

Comment: @Stephen Doh. I wouldn't care if I hadn't actually been thinking row, column and still I got it wrong.

Comment: yea, that's going to end up with "Apples" "Bananas" or the like as the range name, not "FruitList"  That *is* what you asked for ('set the name box of E5 to the contents of D5') but I see how we looked at the image instead of that sentence. Oops :-)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you're looking for

```
Range("A2:A6").Name = "FruitList"
```

Comment: snap, great minds thinking alike

Answer (score 3):

From VBA you can do it with

```
activesheet.range("A2:A6").name="Fruitlist"
```